# ¿Como puedo trabar con caracteres asiáticos en Windows?

Tags: c++, c

tengo un problema al querer trabajar con caracteres asiáticos en c++, quiero construir un chat, de alguna forma, en la cual pueda trabar con caracteres asiáticos, he leído, considero yo, suficiente información para entender, como funciona Unicode o los Code Pages, teniendo en cuenta que los caracteres Unicode, requieren mas memoria para almacenar un carácter y puede llegar a ser un gran desperdicio, quisiera trabajar con Code Pages, he buscado algunos tutoriales pero no encuentro nada realmente que me sea útil, cuando intento compilar en mi plataforma de Windows y solo obtengo caracteres extraños como en el siguiente caso

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(949); // Establece la página de códigos como coreano (Korean Code Page)

    std::cout << "안녕하세요" << std::endl; // "안녕하세요" significa "hola" en coreano

    return 0;
}
```

esta es la salida :
[image: execute]

he visto algunos tutoriales y otras preguntas en stack overflow en ingles y dicen que puede llegar a ser una mala configuracion de la terminal, si ya habido alguna publicacion en español sobre esto quisiera que me ayuden entender

Comment: Una cosa es que tu programa use un code page específico y otra cosa es que la consola del sistema use su propio codepage. Para que los caracteres se vean bien, no sólo basta con configurarlos en el programa, el entorno (la consola del sistema operativo) debe estar configurado para reconocer estos caracteres.

Comment: No te preocupes por la memoria. Es 2023 y hasta tu teléfono tiene más memoria que una computadora de hace 10 años. Usa Unicode como la mayoría de personas y podrás obtener mejor ayuda que con otras codificaciones.

Comment: Con UTF-8 necesitarás 3 bytes por cada carácter CJK mientras que con UTF-16 solo 2. https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+5580

Answer (score 0):

Diferente del **ASCII** que solo tiene letras acentuadas, **UTF-8** representa todos estos caracteres.

En tu código, incluso al especificar el enconding `949` **EUC-KR**, algunas versiones de Windows pueden no estar configuradas para el **encoding** `UTF-8`, que abarca más caracteres.

Te recomiendo visitar la página de soporte de Windows y verificar si la versión que estás utilizando tiene configurado el encoding UTF-8. En caso de que no lo tenga, sigue las instrucciones de soporte para configurar el encoding UTF-8.

La forma recomendada de usar `UTF-8` en el código es:

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)
```

Esto mostrará todos los caracteres coreanos.

Otro detalle que puede ayudar es utilizar la función `setlocale`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    locale::global(locale("ko_KR.UTF-8"));  // coreano UTF-8

     
    return 0;
}
```

Al utilizar esta función, se mantendrán las convenciones y reglas específicas del idioma coreano.

Sin embargo, para asegurarte, debes verificar si el sistema que estás utilizando tiene configurado `UTF-8`.

Comment: A tener en cuenta que para imprimir literales correctamente el código fuente tiene que tener la misma codificación y puede que sea necesario realizar algunas configuraciones adicionales en el compilador.

Comment: @cardosource, cuando compilo aparece otro error